# Which CodeIgniter-like program for PHP, based on my idea?

Tags: php

What is the best program like CodeIgniter for PHP that I should use to create a student database system?

I'm doing this as just a random project so that I can learn about these types of programs.

I just wanted to ask the more experienced users what they would recommend.

Thank you.

Comment: See PHP Frameworks : www.phpframeworks.com

Comment: A very **CodeIgniter like** framework is Kohana, since it was originally a form of CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'CodeIgniter-like programs' I assume you are asking about PHP Web frameworks. There is a very comprehsive list available here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#PHP_2.

There are plenty to choose from some of the most popular (in my opinion) are:

- Zend
- CakePHP
- CodeIgniter
- Kohana
- Yii
- Symfony
- Drupal

You'll want to figure out what version of PHP you have access to as some frameworks only work with PHP 5.3+. All are capable of anything you can make and I feel it really comes down to coding preference for what framework you choose to work with.